# C# How do I know when to make a property both read and write rather than just read-only

Tags: c#, properties, get, set

I know the difference between read and write in properties,

I understand that you can only read from properties that are read only (only using the getter) but when it comes to the write keyword (the setter) how do I know which properties to apply this to?

Simply put, my question is - What question do you ask yourself about the property you're writing when your applying get and set accesses to it?

My next question would be if you don't provide a set access to the property, how on earth does it get defined?

Thanks heaps if you help me.

Comment: What does a setter let you do with that property?  You write the setter if you want to be able to do that: to set the property via assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A read-only property is something determined by the class that nothing outside the class should be able to change. For example, consider a `List<string>`. It has a `Count` property. It wouldn't make sense to be able to do this:

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Count = 5;
```

What sets the read-only property? Its value changes when items are added to or removed from the list. So that's one example, where a property reflects some internal state of a class. Another example is the `StopWatch` class. You can't set the value of `ElapsedMilliseconds`. That property is determined by how much time has passed since the clock started.

Here's another example.

```
public class Price
{
    public decimal Amount {get; private set;}
    public Price(decimal amount)
    {
        if(amount < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount", 
            "amount must be greater than zero.");
        Amount = amount;
    }

    public Void Discount(decimal discountAmount)
    {
        if(discountAmount >= amount)
            amount = 0
        else
            amount -= discountAmount;
    }
}
```

`Amount` is read-only. There are two ways to set `Amount`. One is when the class is created, by passing an amount to the constructor.

```
var myPrice = new Price(5);
```

The other is by calling the `Discount` method.

```
myPrice.Discount(3);
```

In both cases the class controls how `Amount` is set so that you can't set it to a negative amount. The class provides methods that allow its state to be changed, but it makes that change it determines what changes are allowed.

In some cases you might want a property or an entire class to be immutable (unchangeable) so that whatever values are determined when the class is created never change.

Comment: Thanks for the time you've taken to explain this.

Comment: My pleasure. If it's the answer please don't forget to mark it a the answer.,

Answer (score 1):

> What question do you ask yourself about the property you're writing
>   when your applying get and set accesses to it?

Simply put it is whether you want to allow users of your class to change that particular property *after* the class has been created. What happens when they do is totally determined by the class.

> My next question would be if you don't provide a set access to the property, 
>   how on earth does it get defined?

1. It can be set via the constructor. It could be a parameter that is
   passed to the constructor, so some hard coded value you want to make
   available.
2. Some properties can be lazily instantiated. Imagine you have two properties on your class called FistName and LastName. You have a
   final property called FullName where it is defined as:

   **result = this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;**

Hope this gets you started on this. If you want to delve more deeply go and have a look at [enter link description here]SOLID[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) and you can always Google for more information on properties.

Comment: Hi TheEdge, thank you. You've mentioned "users of your class" just wanted specification on who exactly is the users of my class? Engineers assisting to write my code or users of my application? Also you mentioned  "to change that particular property after the class has been created". My question on this is

Comment: Accidentally sent without completing previous comment. Does after the class has been created mean after my application is live? Thanks again.

Comment: Users of your class = anyone who has access to your class in code. That is anyone using your class. As I don't know whether the class is in an assembly you shared with others, common code, accessible via a web API I cannot be more definitive.

Comment: after class has been created = whenever the class is **instantiated** or constructed.